# GLSL Shader: Mapping Bars in Polar-Coordinates

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, polar-coordinates

I'd like to create a polar representation of this shader: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4sfSDN

So that it looks like in this screenshot:
http://postimg.org/image/uwc34jxxz/

I know the basics of the polar-system: How to calculate r and ϕ, but i can only use those values with a texture2d() load function on a image.

When i only have a amplitude value like in the shader above, i dont get it working.

r should somehow be based of the amplitude, but then i dont know how to draw the circle without the texture2d() function... i can draw a circle with r only, but then there are no different amplitudes. Or do i even need to fill a matrix with the generated bars in a loop and load the circle from there?

Im quite sure it is possible, because of the insane shaders on shadertoy, but i dont quite get it... 
Can anyone point me out to a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the shader you posted I think it should be enough to simply transform the `uv` to polar coordinates.

So what you are looking for are angle and radius from the center. First let us transform the `uv` so it gives the vector pointing from the center:

```
uv = fragCoord - (iResolution*.5);
```

Next try to normalize it. Since the view is not square the normalization transform should only be by 1 coordinate such that

```
if(iResolution.x>iResolution.y)
{
   uv = uv/iResolution.y;
}
else
{
   uv = uv/iResolution.x;
}
```

This will kind of produce a fit effect but you may just hard code one or the other if you need to. `min` can be used if available (`uv = uv/min(iResolution.x, iResolution.y))`) to remove the condition.

So at this point the `uv` vector points from the center toward the pixel position in a coordinate system that is normalized in one dimension.

Now to get the angle you may simply use `atan(uv.y, uv.x)`. To get the radius you then need `length(uv)`.

The radius in your case will be for the shorter dimension in range [0, .5] so you may multiply it by 2.0 but this is a factor you may later change to get the desired effect so that the maximum value is not hitting the border but maybe having 80% or so (just play around with it).

The angle is in range of [-Pi, Pi] plus in the docs it says it does not work for `X = 0` which you will need to handle yourself then. So now the angle must be transformed to be in range [.0, 1.0] to access the texture coordinate:

```
angle = angle/(Pi*2.0) + .5
```

So now construct the new `uv`

```
uv = vec2(angle, radius)
```

And use the same shader you did before.

You will also need to keep in mind that radius may be larger then 1.0 in corners which may produce a wrong texture access. In such cases it would be best to discard the fragment.

From the shader toy:

```
#define M_PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy - (iResolution.xy*.5);
    uv = uv/min(iResolution.x, iResolution.y);
    float angle = atan(uv.y, uv.x);
    angle = angle/(M_PI*2.0) + .5;
    float radius = length(uv);
    uv = vec2(angle, radius*2.0);

    float bars = 24.;
    float fft  = texture2D( iChannel0, vec2(floor(uv.x*bars)/bars,0.25) ).x;
    float amp = (fft - uv.y)*100.;
    fragColor = vec4(amp,0.,0.,1.0);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this did the trick! nice! but i had to use "angle = angle/(Pi*2.0) + 0.5" (not 1.0) to map the angle value to [0.0-1.0]... is this right? I checked the values with a jfiddle:[link](https://jsfiddle.net/c91yyxw6/)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I made a mistake as I was writing it out of my head. Let me fix this..

Comment: Before the frag color line add if(ceil(uv.x*bars)-uv.x*bars < .1) amp = .0;